# cannot find -lopencv_contrib cannot find -lopencv_legacy

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed opencv it compiled 100%, i have run a command:
**pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv**
It's output is:-**I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv4 -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui**

But when i try to compile a c++ code it gives cannot find error,
I don't know what to do.
Thanks..

~/cpp_test$

```
g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lopencv_legacy
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Check if the ``opencv_contrib.so`` and ``opencv_legacy.so`` are in the ``/usr/lib`` folder, if not, create symlinks to the actual library files in  ``/usr/lib``

Answer (score 4):

If you installed OpenCV 4, I'm pretty confident that you met the same problem as mine.

The solution is actually pretty simple, you just need to run

```
g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

instead of

```
g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Answer (score 0):

after installation of Opencv, symbolic linking has to be done to make a link for the library to a known lib location. 
Try the command on terminal `sudo ldconfig`, to dynamically link the library.

And then compile `g++ main.cpp -o  output $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`.

Comment: I have done all the steps then i have done 'sudo ldconfig'. to compile c++ code i have used exact same command

Comment: /cpp_test$ **g++ main.cpp -o  output $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)           **
**Output:  /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lopencv_legacy
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: The problem is weird. Search for the Opencv build folder and try finding `libopencv_contrib.so` and `libopencv_legacy.so`. Once found, do `sudo ln /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld/libopencv_legacy.so` and then compile the code. If it does not work try uninstalling and reinstalling opencv.